# Need help confirming password after validation

Tags: java, string, passwords

The main program should ask for a password that is 8 characters, 1 upper, 1 lower & 1 digit. Once passed requirements it should ask the user to re-enter the password and check that the two passwords match. I need help adding that section to my code. Currently, the code compiles with no problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PassChecker2 {

   public static void main (String [] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       String inputPassword;
       System.out.println(" Please enter your Password:");
       inputPassword = input.next();

       System.out.println(checkerPass(inputPassword));
       System.out.println("");

       //main(args);                     

   }
   public static boolean lenthgCk (String password) {

          if (password.length() > 7) {

             if(checkerPass(password)) {
                return true;
          }
         }
          else {
            System.out.println("Password must be at least 8 characters long.");
            return false;
          }
            return true;
         } 

   public static boolean checkerPass (String password) { 

      boolean hasUpperCase = false;
      boolean hasLowerCase = false;
      boolean hasDigit = false;
      char c;

      for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {

          c = password.charAt(i);  
          if(Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
             hasUpperCase = true;
          }
          else if(Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
             hasLowerCase = true;
          }
          else if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
             hasDigit = true;
          }
          if(hasUpperCase && hasLowerCase && hasDigit) {
             return true;
          }
          else {     
          System.out.println("Password is invalid must meet all requirements.");
          return false;
          }
   }
          return true;
          }

  }
```

Comment: Compare the passwords? String1.equals(String2);?

Comment: This is a wonderful example on why code format matters. Your `return` statements are inside the loop.

Comment: ok I'll correct thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just input another string the same way you inputted the original password and check that they are both equal:

```
System.out.println(" Please confirm your Password:");
Stirng confirmPassword = input.next();

if (!confirmPassword.equals(inputPassword)) {
    System.out.println("Passwords do not match");
    // And possibly exit the program here?
}
```

Comment: would I have to create a whole new method for it or just simply add it to the main method?

Comment: @SamaliiiRose both are valid choices